# preg_replace / str_replace : Inline / line break

Tags: php, regex, csv, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm looking for an exemple to replace all my spaces to an "inline" i think in english it's line break.

This an exemple of my CSV file:

```
    "6543945";"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";"5017";"EnginSouhaite";"D";"1";"ne circule pas"
"6543945";"1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100001010000101000010100001010000101000010100001010000101100010100001010000101111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110001111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000";"5017";"EnginSouhaite";"D";"1";"Q JUSQU'AU 30/01/16 ; VE DF DU 31/01 AU 15/04/16 ; Q A PARTIR DU 17/04/16 (NE CIRCULE PAS 29,30,31/10/16)"
"6543946";"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";"5017";"EnginSouhaite";"D";"1";"ne circule pas"
"6543946";"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";"5017";"EnginSouhaite";"D";"1";"ne circule pas"
"6543945";"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";"5017";"EnginSouhaite";"D";"2";"ne circule pas"
"6543946";"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";"5017";"EnginSouhaite";"D";"2";"ne circule pas"
```

First, i decide to replace all my '/"/' to spaces (' '), like that:

```
foreach( $tableau as $row )  {   

    $replace = preg_replace('/"/', ' ', $tableau[$i]);

    echo $replace; ?> <br/> <?php 

    $i += 1;
}
```

This is the result:

```
6543945 
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
5017 
EnginSouhaite 
D 
1 
ne circule pas 6543945 
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100001010000101000010100001010000101000010100001010000101100010100001010000101111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110001111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000
5017 
EnginSouhaite 
D 
1 
Q JUSQU'AU 30/01/16 
VE DF DU 31/01 AU 15/04/16 
Q A PARTIR DU 17/04/16 (NE CIRCULE PAS 29,30,31/10/16) 6543946
```

As you can see, i want (and i prefer) to do an inline. Because you can see some number like "654XXX" are next to "ne circule pas", and for me, i need these number are inline.

Anyone have a solution ? I had test something like this:

```
$replace2 = preg_replace(' ', '/$\n/',$replace);
```

This is wrong, and I think that's a big mistake.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "inline"? Could you post an example of how the result should look?

Comment: You see in my post, my result: and for example, all my line begin with a number like "654xxx". As you can see, this line: "Q A PARTIR DU 17/04/16 (NE CIRCULE PAS 29,30,31/10/16) 6543946 " is the last line in the CSV file. And we can find my number "654xxx" next to this line. I need to have my number under my line, like this: (Q A .... NE CIRCULE PAS...)  <br/> *line break* \n, 654xxx. I hope you understand (I will edit if it's not correct)

Comment: Hmm, you currently have structured CSV data, so I'd take advantage of that and parse it using something like `str_getcsv()`. Then once you have the data in an array, it's straightforward to print it any way you want. Using Regex might work in some cases, but might break in others, so it's better to deal with the CSV directly.

Comment: Thanks, i will try this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to replace the line break (ie. `\r\n`) by `<br>`:

```
foreach( $tableau as $row )  {   
    $replace = preg_replace('/"/', ' ', $row);
    $replace = preg_replace('/\R/', '<br>', $replace);
    echo $replace, '<br>';
}
```

`\R` stands for any kind of linebreak.
I also remove the use of `$i` as it is not needed because in the for loop `$tableau[$i]` is the same as `$row`

Comment: Thanks for your help and your explanation!

Comment: @A.Rouze: « Il n'y a pas de quoi. »

Answer (score 0):

Edited:
You can achive your result this way as well

```
foreach( $tableau as $row )  { 
    $replace = preg_replace('/"/', ' ', $row);        
    $replace_arr = explode (';',$replace);
    foreach ($replace_arr as $key=>$val){
        echo $val."<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I'm testing that and the result is the same. I search how to line break before my "id" number, "654xxx"

Comment: Why are you escaping the double quote? How is this different from OP?

Comment: No, sorry for my english.. "This is the result ... " it's seems like what I show to the user. You can see the solution above. Thanks for your help